# Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)

Tags: c, pointers

The aim of the exercise is to allocate n-lines of the triangle of tartar. My idea was to use pointers to pointers to allocate it.
However when runned the process ends in this way: Process finished with

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int somma (int x) {
int sum=0;
for (int i=0; i<=x; i++) {
  x=x-i;
  sum+=x;
}
return sum;
} 


  void stampa (int **a, int x) {
    *(*(a+0)+0)=1;

    for (int j=1; j<x; j++) {
        *(*(a+0)+j)=0;
    }

    for (int i=1; i<x; i++) {
        *(*(a+i)+0)=1;
        for (int j=1; j<x; j++) {
            *(*(a+i)+j)=*(*(a+i-1)+j-1)+*(*(a+i-1)+j);
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<=i; j++ ) {
            printf(" %3d", *(*(a+i)+j));

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
 }
int main() {
   int x, **mat=NULL;
   printf("Inserisci x:"); //insert x.
   scanf("%d", &x);
   int sum=somma(x);

 
   mat=(int**)malloc(sum*sizeof(int*));
   if (mat==NULL) {
       return 1;
   }
    stampa(mat, x); //print function.

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why `void *stampa` if you don't return?

Comment: what `x` did you input when said error popped up?

Comment: i didn't want to have a return value (?)

Comment: @sim: Then declare the return type to be `void` instead of `void*`.

Comment: `0xC00000FD` is the error code for [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow).

Comment: any x I input  makes it happen

Answer (score 0):

isn't  `*(*(a+i-1)+j)` equal to a[-1] since you declared `int i=0` in the loop just above?

Comment: do you mean *(*(a+1-1)+j)? this is a mistake I didn't notice

Comment: I'm quite sure that the function itself works, because when I ran it without allocating it printed what I was expecting

Comment: that 1-1 was suspicious, please correct it in the question, but I meant, a+i-1 in the first iteration. Isn't i == 0? So aren't you basically doing a-1? (I might be confused)

Comment: I'm referring to the end of `*(*(a+i)+j)=*(*(a+1-1)+j-1)+*(*(a+i-1)+j);`

Comment: @sim: Re “I’m quite sure that the function itself works, because when I ran it without allocating it printed what I was expecting”: That is an insufficient test to ensure a function does not have a bug.

Comment: @emetsipe oh yes, another mistake sorry.

Comment: @emetsipe i just found the solution. I just made a compiling mistake (1 instead of i). Thank u for ur advices

Comment: @EricPostpischil oh ok, I've just started coding so I'm not very skilled in it

Comment: @emetsipe But now idk why if I put "sum" (the result of a function that sums every number lower than an input value (included) in the malloc. The function "somma" returns an integer, so why doesn't it work?

Comment: you need to fix the formatting of the question btw

Comment: @emetsipe already tried but unsuccessfully :'((

Comment: @emetsipe did it

Comment: if I'm not wrong, the problem is you are initializing only the first array, buy you have an array of pointers which you have to define too. Before you used x*x I believe, which was ok because it is one of the possibilities to declare an int ** in malloc (both dimensions); now you are only declaring the size of the first dimension, the pointers that will have size of (int *). The declaration of those int * is missing.

Comment: @emetsipe oh yeah, ur not wrong. If i put sum*sum it works, but if I put a lower number (like 1) it doesn't work. I guess it is because the allocated memory is too short. then, what shoud I have to do if i wanna allocate the minimum size of memory to contain this matrix? P.S I have just discovered that just "sum" is enough to store it only for two lines

Comment: @emetsipe it works for just two lines with any size :((

Comment: You need to define the size of the "secondary" pointers somehow. Sorry I've just learnt this topic so I'm not 100% sure about this stuff. What I use for these situations is the 3rd way you find [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/) so that would be a for loop. But multiplying sum by the desired size works the same. It will read the two factors as the size for "first" and "second" pointers.

Comment: if you put only one value, you are not setting the size for the pointers you point to, that's why any value you write gives you the same result

Comment: just find the size you need and put it as (sum*your_value) as you did before with sum*sum. I can't help you with finding the value since I don't fully understand what your program does ;(

Comment: but even if I put sum*sum it doesn't work

Comment: is sum the only thing you changed? did it work before?

Comment: no, it didn't work

Comment: I mean was the program working before adding all the sum stuff?

Comment: yeah, the programme works correctly. If I don't allocate a certain size of memory it works

Comment: sorry I don't really know how to help you further

Comment: @emetsipe no problem. I really appreciated ur help :))

Comment: "The aim of the exercise is to allocate n-lines of the triangle of tartar" could you explain? You have to allocate in what? Arrays? And allocate lines like 1, 1-1, 1-2-1 would be three lines?

Comment: @emetsipe the aim is to allocate the minum size of memory. THe programme should print 1; 1-1; 1 2 1; 1 3 3 1; 1 4 6 4 1...: each ";" means a new line

Answer (score 0):

So, I took Tartaglia's triangle, I opened VS Code and I wrote an algorithm (It's night and I'm a beginner, don't scream). I hope it can help you.

A couple of notes before the code:

1. I use square brackets and array arithmetic, but you can use your preferred notation, it should work the same.
2. The algorithm won't be great or the most efficient but it works.
3. The program creates a x*x matrix (dynamically allocating an array to arrays), then it puts the right numbers at the right place.
4. The `tartaglia` function only allocates the needed numbers, but for easier code you can just fill the whole matrix.
5. The matrix can be thought as watching the triangle after tilting your head to the right, so the first row basically corresponds to the right side of the triangle; the `stampa` function however prints the actual lines, so it loops through the matrix diagonally.

This is a basic program that works, so you have a base to work  on. Remove what's useless and modify it as you need.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void tartaglia(int **matrix, int x){
    int k=x-1; // I'm initializing only values I'll print, so the number of columns decreases for each row
    for (int i=1; i<x-1; i++){
        for (int j=1; j<k; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = (matrix[i][j-1]) + (matrix[i-1][j]); // sums the two values above in the triangle
        }
        k--;
    }
}

void stampa(int **matrix, int x){
    for (int line=0; line<x; line++){ //lines to print (go from 0 to x-1)
        int i = line;
        int j = 0;
        printf("\n");
        for (int z=0; z<=line; z++){ // z= numbers in each line
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
            i--;
            j++;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int x;
    //prompting input x, will be size of matrix (x*x)
    printf("Inserisci x:"); 
    scanf("%d", &x);

    //dynamically allocating pointer of pointers
    int **matrix = (int**) malloc(x*sizeof(int*));
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++){
        matrix[i] = (int *) malloc(x*sizeof(int));
        for (int j=0; j<x; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = 1; // just initializing the whole matrix
        }
    }

    tartaglia(matrix, x); //this function actually puts the values into the matrix
    stampa(matrix, x); //this function prints the values

}
```

Feel free to ask for any doubts.

Comment: i think i would (in the second allocation) put x-i instead of x, in order to allocate just the values that i need to search. Idk if it's useful or totally wrong lol

Comment: do you mean in the second dimension? Having x*(x-1)?

Comment: just x-1 in the second dimension

Comment: or maybe for(int i=x; i>0; i--) { matrix[i]=(int*)malloc((x-i)*sizeof(int)) }

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: if you are trying to use as less memory as possible, maybe the x*(x-1) matrix is better, you allocate x less cells. You will need to  add a "1" at the end of the output, since you aren't storing that last cell anymore

Comment: okok thank you <3

Comment: but you need to check if the for loops that handled columns need to be changed, I think they shouldn't but check again, I'm too tired to read the whole code again. Anyways once you have this working version you can make all the changes you want and go back if they don't work